# How can I populate by bar chart with required data?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, reactjs

I have the bar chart here:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { months } from "../../helpers/utils";
import Axios from "axios"; //axios library to make requests to api

// Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Roboto, sans-serif";
function BarChart() {
  //retrieving data from api
  const [intentsList, setintentsList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/countintents").then((response) => {
      setintentsList(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
    });
  }, []);
  // BarChart
  //const labels = Object.keys(intentsList);
  const data = {
    labels: Object.keys(intentsList),
    datasets: [
      {
        axis: "y",
        label: "My First Dataset",
        data: Object.values(intentsList),
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: [
          "rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
          "rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)",
          "rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)",
          "rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)",
          "rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)",
          "rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)",
          "rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)",
        ],
        borderColor: [
          "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
          "rgb(255, 159, 64)",
          "rgb(255, 205, 86)",
          "rgb(75, 192, 192)",
          "rgb(54, 162, 235)",
          "rgb(153, 102, 255)",
          "rgb(201, 203, 207)",
        ],
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
    ],
  };
  const options = {
    indexAxis: "y",
    // Elements options apply to all of the options unless overridden in a dataset
    // In this case, we are setting the border of each horizontal bar to be 2px wide
    elements: {
      bar: {
        borderWidth: 2,
      },
    },
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        position: "right",
        display: false,
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: "Chart.js Horizontal Bar Chart",
      },
    },
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Bar data={data} options={options} /> {/* Props */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default BarChart;
```

Backend code:

```
app.get("/countintents", (req, res) => {
  db.query(
    "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN intent IN ('Products', 'Land Transport') THEN 1 END) AS products, SUM(CASE WHEN intent IN ('Air Freight', 'Industry Solutions', 'Aerospace and Defense') THEN 1 END) AS industry_solutions, SUM(CASE WHEN intent in ('Profile', 'Contact Us') THEN 1 END) AS about_us FROM data_analytics",
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

And this backend code has allowed me to retrieve this data in api endpoint /countintents
which is : [{"products":2,"industry_solutions":3,"about_us":2}]

and this is in the intentsList where I receive it. My question is how can I populate my bar chart to show labels as Products, Industry_solutions, About_us and data as 2,3,2 accordingly to what I receive.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will always get one result from your query. You may modify your backend code to return the first object/result retrieved from your query instead of the array of results. Your client side logic already uses `Object.keys` and `Object.values` to extract the respective labels and values.

```js
app.get("/countintents", (req, res) => {
  db.query(
    "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN intent IN ('Products', 'Land Transport') THEN 1 END) AS products, SUM(CASE WHEN intent IN ('Air Freight', 'Industry Solutions', 'Aerospace and Defense') THEN 1 END) AS industry_solutions, SUM(CASE WHEN intent in ('Profile', 'Contact Us') THEN 1 END) AS about_us FROM data_analytics",
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result[0]); //modified to return first record
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: why I'ld need to return first record?

Comment: the first record has your desired data as an object

Comment: but doesn't it return
[{"products":2,"industry_solutions":3,"about_us":2}]

So it'll just be products:2?